# elisp function replace selection

Tags: emacs, replace, elisp

I have a `replace-regexp` that I use frequently, so I want to make it into a function. But <kbd>M-x</kbd>`replace-regexp` either scans the document or uses the selected region; the function I've written seems only to scan the document. How can I get it to work just the same as <kbd>M-x</kbd>`replace-regexp` when I call `my-scripture-links`, particularly with respect to selection or no-selection?

```
(defun my-scripture-links ()
  (interactive)
  (replace-regexp "^\(.*[0-9]+?:[0-9]+\)" "[[https://www.lds.org/scriptures/search?lang=eng&query=\1&x=0&y=0][\1]]"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments for `replace-regexp` are

> (replace-regexp REGEXP TO-STRING &optional DELIMITED START END)

To replace only within a region you need to specify the `START` and `END` of the region.  You can get these from the functions `region-beginning` and `region-end`.  To change behaviour based on whether the region is active or not, just check `region-active-p`.  This will replace within the region if it is active.

```
(defun my-scripture-links ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (replace-regexp "^\(.*[0-9]+?:[0-9]+\)" "[[https://www.lds.org/scriptures/search?lang=eng&query=\1&x=0&y=0][\1]]"
                      nil (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (replace-regexp "^\(.*[0-9]+?:[0-9]+\)" "[[https://www.lds.org/scriptures/search?lang=eng&query=\1&x=0&y=0][\1]]")
     ))
```

Comment: See also `(interactive "r")`

Comment: Excellent! Turns out my regexp is broken; for some reason you need to use double \ so \\\) and not just \\) in functions. If you'll update to account for this, I'll mark it answered.

Comment: WorldsEndless: The reason is that backslash is the escape character for double-quoted strings, so to include a literal backslash you need to double it. Hence `"\\(foo\\|bar\\)"` for the regexp `\(foo\|bar\)`